# After filtering, get count of items currently displayed in a Grid widget in Vaadin 14 web app

Tags: count, datagrid, filtering, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In the [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.html) widget of Vaadin 14, backed by a [`ListDataProvider`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html), after applying a filter(s) via a call such as [`setFilter`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html#setFilter-com.vaadin.flow.function.SerializablePredicate-) or `addFilter`…

➥ How does one detect **how many of the items in the data provider are currently displayed** to the user?

I have noticed the [`ListDataProvider::size`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ListDataProvider.html#size-com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.Query-) method. But that method takes a `Query` with a `SerializablePredicate`. My multiple filters have already been successfully applied, and my `Grid` is showing a subset of the data provider's items. So I do not want to run another query. I want to know the results of the filters *already* applied.

Comment: `ListDataProvider` has a public method `size` but you need to provide a query of type `Query<T, SerializablePredicate<T>>`. Once you find out how to build that query object with the current filters etc this should work out. Do you need help with creating the query, or is mentioning the `ListDataProvider::size` method enough for you?

Comment: @kscherrer My multiple filters are already applied and working. The `Grid` widget is already showing a subset of items. I noticed that `size` method taking a predicate, but that makes no sense. My filters have already taken effect. So I do *not* need to run a new predicate. I want to know the results of the filters/predicates *already* run. I added a note on this to my Question. Thanks for raising the issue. And please correct me if I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But the dataprovider is not storing the results of a filtered resultset anywhere, from which you would want to ask its size. It only knows the complete list of items. Therefore for a size call to work you need to specify again which filters it needs to apply to the complete list of items. You don't have to rebuild the filters; you can get the current filter from the dataprovider for building the query parameter.

Comment: I do agree that in theory there should be a method that does this all for you, because the dataprovider *does* know the current filter/predicate already. A method `filteredSize()` should exist for this, expecting *no* parameter. Maybe create a feature request in their github?

Comment: @kscherrer I see (I think). Unfortunately, I do not know how to get my current filter and pass to the `size` method. The `ListDataProvider::getFilter` returns a `SerializablePredicate<T>` but the `ListDataProvider::size` method takes a `Query<T,SerializablePredicate<T>>`. I have no idea how to turn the predicate into a query.

Comment: I'll have a look and post an answer once I find out.

Comment: @kscherrer Turning the predicate into a Query is too easy: there is a constructor for Query taking a SerializablePredicate. `int size = dataProvider.size( new Query( dataProvider.getFilter() ) );`. If you want to write up an Answer for all this, I'll accept it. If not, I'll write one. Meanwhile, I will post a feature request as you suggested.

Comment: I'm currently testing it with my application. I will write one if you don't mind. thx for making the feature request.

Comment: I posted feature request: [*Add `filteredSize` method to `DataProvider` or `ListDataProvider` #7539*](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7539).

Comment: @kscherrer And a parallel question: How to get the overall size of the data provider, the count of all items *before* filtering? I want to display a label to the user saying "Now showing 6 of 10 items".

Comment: You can do `dataProvider.getItems().size()` for the complete item size. I used that also directly within my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pass `new Query<>( myDataProvider.getFilter() )` to `ListDataProvider::size`

`ListDataProvider` has the method `size(Query<T, SerializablePredicate<T>> query)`.

Because the dataprovider only keeps the original list of items, a simple `size` method without parameters would not work as you wanted. You can build the required query using the current filters of your dataprovider.

I tested the following code and it works:

```
// my own method, defined as value change listeners of any filter field
private void onFilterChange(){
    ListDataProvider<Foo> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<Foo>) grid.getDataProvider();
    dataProvider.setFilter((item) -> {......}

    // everytime after resetting the filter, check how many items now are displayed
    int filteredSize = dataProvider.size(new Query<>(dataProvider.getFilter()));

    int fullSize = dataProvider.getItems().size(); // this is how you get the size of all items
    Notification.show(String.format("Now showing %d of %d items", filteredSize, fullSize));
}
```

Perhaps in the future this work might be a little easier: See feature-request ticket [*Add `filteredSize` method to `DataProvider` or `ListDataProvider` #7539*](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7539).

Comment: Good, thanks. FYI, regarding listeners, I used [`AbstractDataProvider::addDataProviderListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.17/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/AbstractDataProvider.html#addDataProviderListener-com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataProviderListener-). For example: `dataProvider.addDataProviderListener( ( DataChangeEvent < MapProfile > dataChangeEvent ) -> {…`

Comment: On what class do I find `onFilterChange`?

Comment: @BasilBourque this is my own method, and I use it as the value change listener of my filter fields like this: `someFilterField.addValueChangeListener(event -> onFilterChange()))`. See [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17689013/17691170) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of concept with a custom `ListDataProvider` that caches the size.

At the time `setFilter` is called, or at the time the `DataProviderListener` is called, the count has not yet been updated. Because of that, we use `UI.getCurrent().beforeClientResponse(...)` to delay the update of the text.

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.addColumn(String::toString).setHeader("Value");

        MyDataProvider<String> myDataProvider = new MyDataProvider<>(
                Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"));
        grid.setDataProvider(myDataProvider);

        Span countSpan = new Span();

        TextField filterField = new TextField("Filter");
        filterField.addValueChangeListener(e ->
                myDataProvider.setFilter(str -> str.contains(e.getValue())));

        // Use beforeClientResponse to give the grid time to filter the results
        myDataProvider.addDataProviderListener(e ->
                UI.getCurrent().beforeClientResponse(this, context ->
                        countSpan.setText(myDataProvider.getCachedSize() + " items in the grid")));

        add(filterField, grid, countSpan);
    }

    private static class MyDataProvider<T> extends ListDataProvider<T> {

        private int cachedSize;

        public MyDataProvider(Collection<T> items) {
            super(items);
        }

        @Override
        public int size(Query<T, SerializablePredicate<T>> query) {
            return (cachedSize = super.size(query));
        }

        public int getCachedSize() {
            return cachedSize;
        }
    }
}
```